# How to escape new line from string

Tags: php

is there any php method to remove new line char from string?

```
$str ="
Hi
there
";
```

my string contains a new line char between 'Hi' and 'there'
i want output as a "Hi there".I don't want to use regular expression.

Answer (score 11):

This is a bit confusing

> is there any php method to remove new line char from string?

It looks like you actually want them replaced with a space.

```
$str = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n", "\r"), ' ', $str);
```

Assuming the replacing goes from left to right, this should suit Windows text files.

The first grouping is to match Windows newlines which use both \r and \n.

Comment: now produces ' Hi there ', if line terminator was both \r and \n as in windows files then you get double spacing

Comment: just needs the double space handler now - almost there (ps will +1 in oo 6 minutes, ty for the limits so)

Comment: @nathan What are you saying will double space - shouldn't the first replace cover the combination with a single space, and then the others will remove the Unix style line endings?

Comment: No reason to use `array("\r\n", "\n", "\r")` ... `array("\n", "\r")` should do it. But then again, if the input's coming from a web browser, "\n" should be enough I think...

Comment: & @no poorly defined q tbh, just think about the input being '\r\nHi\r\n\r\nThere\r\n' or worse with say 6 \n's in a row - regex is only 'real' way to handle all scenarios, what alex has suggested cuts it for str_replace imho though (if he'd edit I could +1 it) ;)

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to escape newline in PHP.

As mentioned in PHP documentation on [strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) after listing all escaped characters:

> As in single quoted strings, escaping any other character will result
>   in the backslash being printed too.

So you can do it by breaking your string in each line and concatenating them by dot like this:

```
$str = "Hi " .
"there" .
"!";
```

Answer (score 5):

`$str=str_replace("\n", "", $str);` should do it.

`"\n"` represents a newline in php.

Comment: misses out \r line termination

Comment: nathan, see my comment on Alex's answer.

Answer (score 3):

To get the expected results, you'll be needing:

```
$str = trim(str_replace( array("\r\n","\r","\n",'  '), ' ' , $str));
```

or with regex (which is fail safe, you can't account for all the additional spacing you may get with str_replace version):

```
$str = trim(preg_replace( array('/\v/','/\s\s+/'), ' ' , $str)); // 'Hi there'
```

Comment: The OP said they don't want to use a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below script.

```
$str=str_replace("\n", "", $str);
```

Thanks